# Setup TL-WN722N WiFi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, tp-link

How do I setup USB WiFi adapter? I downloaded driver from [TP-Link](http://tp-link.com/) website but when I run `make` it shows make error 2.

When I run make command:

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build M=/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:140: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/.tmp_versions’: Permission denied
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create /home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/.tmp_rtw_cmd.o: Permission denied
/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.c:1:0: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
 /******************************************************************************

scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/creepper/Downloads/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-46-generic'
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)