# cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode

Tags: drivers, kernel, make, dd

This is my simple drivers Makefile:

```
obj-m+=hello_world_module.o
KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules  
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

and the driver code is:

[image]

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/module.h>

static int __hello_world_init(void)
{
    printf(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
    printf(KERN_INFO "module inserted\n");
    return 0;
}

void __exit hello_world_exit(void)
{
    printf(KERN_INFO "module removed\n");
    printf("exit\n");
}

module_init(hello_world_init);
module_exit(hello_world_exit);
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sridhar G");
```

When I run `sudo make` I get this error:

[image]

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/build M=/home/sridhar/Documents
/DD/hello_world_module modules  
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/sridhar/Documents/DD/hello_world_module/hello_world_module.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:339: recipe for target '/home/sridhar/Documents
/DD/hello_world_module/hello_world_module.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/sridhar/Documents/DD/hello_world_module
/hello_world_module.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/sridhar/Documents
/DD/hello_world_module' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sridhar/Documents/DD/hello_world_module] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-30-generic'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text! Paste the text instead and format it with the `{}` button. This way we can copy&paste it to try out your code instead of having to retype it!

Comment: Related: [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)