# error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode

Tags: wireless, kernel, 18.04, error-handling, ubuntu-drivers

I am having wifi range issues in Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the Realtek driver software from GitHub and after extracting the file to desktop and was running the make command.

`allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex$ make`

After running this command I get the following error.

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/build M=/home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
CC [M]  /home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/base.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/allen/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-33-generic'
Makefile:57: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)