# Installing RTAI 5.0 with linux kernel 3.18.20 in Linux 18.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, make

I tried to use the command

```
make
```

or

```
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-rtai
```

I got the following error -

```
CHK     include/config/kernel.release
CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CC      kernel/bounds.s
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:980: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Any ideas?
I have tried this: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)

Comment: What do you mean by kernel 3.18.20? Ubuntu 18.04 does not use this kernel. This is a very old kernel.

Comment: I know it uses 4.15. The kernel 3.18.20 is for installing rtai 5.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)

Comment: I have tried that but it still did not work.