# Getting a "*** [all] Error 2" error when executing make

Tags: make

I'm trying to increase the signal strength of my wifi and this code appears when trying to make:

```
spectre@spectre-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-36-generic/build M=/home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/base.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master/base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/spectre/Desktop/rtlwifi_new-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic'
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have also already installed `linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic` and `make`.
Anyone have suggestions, for I've been away from Ubuntu for a while?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel doesn't support PIC mode for compiling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling)

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the `rtlwifi_new-master.zip` from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) and did a **make**, and it all worked fine.

I suspect that you might not have read the README.md file where it calls out some pre-requisite apps, so do...

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git dkms
```

Also note that this is a `dkms` driver, so the proper way to install it is to install **dkms**, then do...

```
sudo cp {the source code folder} to /usr/src
sudo dkms add...
sudo dkms build...
sudo dkms install...
dkms status
```

type `man dkms` for help.