# driver builds on one machine but not other: code model kernel does not support PIC mode

Tags: drivers, kernel, make

I have a driver for custom hardware, which I rebuild every time the kernel version updates. I have two different Ubuntu 18.04 machines, both of which are running the same version of gcc (`gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`). On one machine, the kernel driver builds as normal. On the second machine, which had Ubuntu reinstalled from scratch in Febuary, it fails to build the kernel driver. I can just copy the driver from the first machine to the second machine, and it works. Why can't the second machine build the driver?

Here is the full output of `make` on the failing machine

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/build M=/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero-base.o
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero-base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero-base.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic'
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'lancero.ko' failed
make: *** [lancero.ko] Error 2
```

Here is the full output of `make` on the working machine:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-96-generic/build M=/home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero-base.o
  CC [M]  /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero-user.o
  LD [M]  /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: Found 1 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
  CC      /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/pcuser/drivers/lancero/Lancero-RELEASE/C/driver/lancero.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic'
```

There are many similar questions, but non seem to have a useful answer. The closest is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling), but that is about compiling the kernel, not a driver. I have tried adding `-fno-pie` flag in the `Makefile` though I'm not 100% sure I did it right since I don't really understand how Makefiles work.

What could be different between these two machines to cause the different behavior?